# Foxit Reader tab navigation keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tabs, navigation, foxit-reader

Is there a way to browse between tabs of different open PDFs in Foxit Reader using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works with version 3.1.1.x of Foxit Reader (on Windows and Linux).

Comment: +1 & CTRL + SHIFT + TAB for backwards navigation

Comment: in OS X, the shortcut is alt-tab and alt-shift-tab

Comment: is there a keyboard shortcut to change the order of the tabs? for example, just take a tab and move it to the right